# Paperclip not updating properly due to routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip (4.2) on my application for a user avatar. When I update my avatar from 'me.jpg' to 'you.jpg' the terminal throws an error of `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/original/me.jpg")`

The avatar DOES upload however it doesn't load like it should. I have a constant image of current_user in my top bar, when i update from me.jpg to you.jpg, the image becomes an icon that represents it wasn't found. Once I reload the page again, the image will appear.

**Full Error**

```
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/original/me.jpg"):
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.6) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/calligouser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/calligouser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/calligouser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/calligouser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/calligouser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (5.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/calligouser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (5.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/calligouser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (56.9ms)
```

**Validations**

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url => "default_pic_male.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**Form**

```
<div class="sub-content">

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :avatar, "Avatar" %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :first_name, "First Name*" %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, { placeholder: "Name" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :last_name, "Last Name*" %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, { placeholder: "Name" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :email, "Email*" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, { placeholder: "Email" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :gender, "Gender*" %>
    <%= f.select :gender, User::GENDERS %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Password (min 8 chars)' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, { placeholder: "Password" } %>
  </div>

  <div class="field-row">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, { placeholder: "Password Confirmation" } %>
  </div>

</div>

<footer>
  <%= f.submit class: 'button right' %>
</footer>
```

**Edit View**

```
<div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="column half">
    <section class="full">

      <header>
        <ul>
          <li><h3>Edit</h3></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
        <%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

          <%= render 'form', f: f %>

        <% end %>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note: I haven't manually set any paths for paperclip. From what I see, when I upload 'you.jpg' it uploads it and replaces 'me.jpg', and then in the terminal it complains I think because it is trying to find 'me.jpg' still? Why, I don't know, i'm not sure if that is the issue at all. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.